# How to set up AppContext.BaseDirectory when hosting CoreCLR with hostfxr

Tags: c++, .net, coreclr

I'm following [this sample/tutorial](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/hosting) to host CoreCLR in my native app using hostfxr,
I've successfully set up the runtime and got the function pointer to call into managed code.

However, in the managed application, the `AppContext.BaseDirectory` property is always an empty string. I tried passing the main exe path with `hostfxr_initialize_parameters.host_path`, still the same. Any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking this on the [dotnet discord](https://aka.ms/dotnet-discord), I figured out that some [runtime properties](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/37151f890257b6e5567a8c8d012270415182e58f/docs/design/features/host-runtime-information.md) like this can be set with [`hostfxr_set_runtime_property_value`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/native-hosting.md#runtime-properties)

Should look like this:

```cpp
// after hostfxr_initialize_for_*
auto set_prop_fptr = (hostfxr_set_runtime_property_value_fn)get_export(lib, "hostfxr_set_runtime_property_value");
set_prop_fptr(cxt, L"APP_CONTEXT_BASE_DIRECTORY", L"C:\\foo");
```